# angularJS - Duplicate Input in Form

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to duplicate two connected inputs in a form. One is a select field and the other a textarea.

I thought I had found a solution but there's a pretty big bug. When removing the last set of inputs, the previous set is overwritten by the items that were just deleted. This makes sense when I look at the implentation. When a delete happens, the index is updated, and then last set of inputs gets the index from the input that was just deleted and the values are overwritten.

The problem is that I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas?

I have included a plunker here. http://plnkr.co/edit/385RWamBaVSq0Cv5zbmq?p=preview

My controller:

```
    function DuplicateInputCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.foodTypes = [
        {
          "code" : "AP",
          "type" : "Apple"
        },
        {
          "code" : "CH",
          "type" : "Chicken"
        },
        {
          "code" : "CH",
          "type" : "Cheese"
        }
      ]

      $scope.foods = [
        {
          "Selection": "",
          "Text": ""
        }
      ]

      $scope.cloneItem = function () {
        var itemToClone = { "Selection": "", "Text": "" };
        $scope.foods.push(itemToClone);
      }

      $scope.removeItem = function (item) {
        $scope.foods.splice(item, 1);
      }

    }
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="DuplicateInputCtrl" class="container">
 <div data-ng-repeat="food in foods">
  <div class="form-group title-field">
    <label for="">Food</label>
    <select class="form-control input-full" data-ng-model="food.Selection"
        data-ng-options="foodType.code as foodType.type for foodType in foodTypes">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden">
    <button data-ng-click="removeItem(food)" class="btn delete-field-{{$index}}">
      Delete
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <textarea class="form-control" data-ng-model="food.Text"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button data-ng-click="cloneItem()" class="btn inline">
  Add
 </button>    
</body>
```

Comment: Just a heads up that your code doesn't currently allow the selection of "Chicken" because it has the same "code" as "Cheese".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no item get overwritten. The problem is that the wrong item is deleted because you are using the `splice()` method incorrectly. The first of its argument should be an index of the item like this:

```
$scope.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
  $scope.foods.splice(itemIndex, 1);
};
```

and in the template, pass the item index by `$index` like this:

```
<button data-ng-click="removeItem($index)" ..
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2SMbeTSqn0v65iKC3SpY?p=preview

PS. Another problem is that you have a duplicate foodType code, `Chicken` and `Cheese` have the same `CH` code. That will make you unable to select the Chicken!

Comment: Thank you. This works. Good spot on the code duplication too. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/hSF1UWtKfQO18n0VlaYQ?p=preview

Just edit your removeItem function.

```
 $scope.removeItem = function (item) {
     index =  $scope.foods.indexOf(item)
     $scope.foods.splice(index, 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 61 you should replace `removeItem(item)` with `removeItem($index)`